# White sludge in coolant tank, overheating and bubbling over

Tags: coolant, sludge

I have an 04 VW Passat. I know it needs a new pcv valve. Could that cause the engine overheating and boiling over with white sludge? What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you've got a blown head gasket.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a blown head gasket is def your issue, the milky sludge is from engine oil mixing w/ coolant. (You didn't recently add any leak-stop to your cooling system right?) You would see bubbles form in the overflow tank or radiator(be very careful opening while hot since spray & boil over is an issue), loss of coolant, possiby w/ no visible leaks underneath the car, & due to this, the engine overheating. A completely blown head gasket will show excessive leaking of coolent. You may have misfires at ignition, loss of power while idling & if the car starts it might not restart after being driven. Hopefully you've discovered the problem already as I'm a bit late. You're prob also seeing white exhaust smoke at ignition. Hope this  info helped from a single female who had 2 learn all about cars at 16 when the combo Ford/Mazda Probe she bought was a POS & to keep from going broke tried 2 diy everything. Lol

Comment: You can also test your coolant for co2, to make sure. You local repair shop should have a testing device.